# What is the best way to add your dataset to a question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that would be better answered if the community had access to the data I was using. The data is quite large, and a small sample wouldn't really do it justice as the scale of the data is important.

The dataset could come in any form, from comma separated values, to server data and which the 'answerer' could copy and paste the data or download the file in the correct format, to fully engage with the issue at hand.

If there is a question about this, or an already-inbuilt ability to do this, then I apologise in advance.

Comment: If its using a database then certainly sqlfiddle. Otherwise pastebin maybe?

Comment: Oh I see, and you just paste the link across! Is it not something that's done enough to warrant its inclusion into the stack exchange site?

Comment: Is the link reliable over the time?

Comment: Well the link won't be reliable over time, but the question and answers hopefully shouldn't rely on the data (even if the answers were reached by playing around with that data). There's a feature-request somewhere (can't find it) asking for an official means to include project files (not the same as this, just similar) because a particular tag would have benefitted, and I think the conclusion reached was that we don't want to encourage questions that can't be reduced down to an SSCCE that fits in the question. This isn't necessarily my opinion, just what I recall.

Comment: With many languages you should be able to provide code that *creates* data with the desired properties relatively easily. E.g., in the [R tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) we have a [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) that explains how to do this with R.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should include all of the data needed to answer your question in the question body itself.  If you truly believe it is a very large amount of data, then explain the data specifics in detail in plain language.  A paragraph or two should be enough to explain it such that it's comprehensible.  If needed, combine the two - perhaps a particularly important relationship between tables can be shown with a small amount of data and the overall structure can be explained in plain language.

If you still don't think that would work - go ask somewhere else.  If it's truly that specific to you that you a) can't show the question in a reasonably small amount of data, and b) can't explain the important details in a paragraph or two, then you're probably looking at a question that won't have much lasting value here, either.  Ask a professor or ask a SQL mailing list or somesuch.