# How can I ask this question without resorting to third-party file sharing?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, minimal-reproducible-example, debugging-questions

I'm working on a program to process a set of PDF files. I'm having trouble and would like to get some assistance on Stack Overflow. In order to show what kind of problems I'm encountering, I need to show both my code and an example PDF document that my code is failing to process correctly, so that readers can replicate the issue. The example PDF document is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yen7x3gezshyynz/Original%20before%20Edit.pdf?dl=0).

But [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266715/619177) indicates that linking to a PDF document on, e.g., Dropbox, should not be done in a Stack Overflow question. How can I get support if I can't share the file? For example, if my problem is, "This function `DeleteAndReplaceAnnotation()` is not producing the annotation I expect when I run it on this PDF file," then how can I demonstrate the problem if I can't link to the PDF file that exhibits the problem? Am I thinking incorrectly about how to structure and present my question?

Comment: You may link to external resources, as far these are essential as input data for your problem. Don't miss to show your debugging efforts though.

Comment: Related: [What is the best way to add your dataset to a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250975) [How do I ask a question about a problem with xib file?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261045)

Comment: That meta answer is at +8/-3; it's not super-reliable as an indicator of consensus.

Comment: The problem with that kind of question is that it boils down to the awfully localized question _"What is the difference between this working PDF and this non-working PDF?"_, where preferably _you_ find the differences, so you can actually ask _"How can I parse fields of type X using library Y?"_, which is in fact findable and usable by others who have the same problem after you.

Comment: @CodeCaster and even more importantly doesn't require a PDF at that point either as people should be able to reproduce the issue on their own with the information provided. The hardest part of asking a question is knowing the right one to ask.

Comment: Why don't you just take a screenshot of the PDF?

Comment: @FaustoNA: PDFs are binary files, and sometimes, when the code appears to be right, one needs to inspect the produced binary to see if the problem is in that file. Layout problems can (and are) be shown with a simple screen shot - but for OPs example question the problem could be deeper.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You are the most qualified person to compare two files on your computer, but maybe Stack Overflow can show you how, rather than doing the comparison for you. You'd be better off first searching for/asking for a technique to compare two PDFs to identify why one is behaving differently when accessed programmatically. Ideally you'd then be able to create your own "malfunctioning" PDF, or at least understand what the parameters  are that lead to the malfunction, which would inform your new question about how to access that type of PDF.

Comment: The title was a little misleading, sounds like it could refer to file sharing as in torrenting. I would suggest changing to `'How can I ask this question without referencing third-party hosted files' / 'files external to SO'` I would edit, but it does not let me. I've probably not used meta.SO enough for the rep points.

Comment: A good MCVE would be able to produce the same output for those looking at the question, without having to see the output file. If you can't provide an MCVE then perhaps your question is simply too broad.

Comment: How large is the PDF? Is it 20,000 bytes or smaller? If so, you can in theory attach it as base64. If not, then what process produces the PDF?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

External links of any kind are discouraged all for similar reasons (can be dead, might be malicious/spam, etc). However, in your case, as has been mentioned in the comments, if you find that you "need" an external source you might consider if you are even asking the correct question.

In your example, if a specific PDF is needed for your question then maybe the question you should be asking is what is the difference between your PDF and another. After that is answered you might still have problems with your code but at that point you no longer "need" a PDF for your question as you can explain the specific uniqueness in your PDF and the code that is unable to handle it. Something more along the lines of "I need help working with PDF feature X using code Y". At that point, no external sources should be needed.

Having said all of that, I would never say never, but I would think that it needs to be an absolute last resort with the consideration that your question may not be handled well if people are unable or unwilling to use the external sources you provide. In fact, an external resource can be a good benefit to your question but mainly if the question can be answered without it.

Usually the hardest part of asking a question is knowing the right one to ask.

Comment: You might want to add that even when the external resource is not needed to answer the question, adding a link to it is a good thing as it simplifies reproducing the problem.

Comment: +1 for _Usually the hardest part of asking a question is knowing the right one to ask._

Comment: Basically you have told that author of the question should have skills to work with PDF as a format when he's using it, i.e. be able to find some features via a hex editor. It's hard to admit, but that's correct. The availability of libraries for PDF doesn't mean the programmer doesn't have to know what it is.

Answer (score 17):

It's not widely known, but

> **[a] PDF file is basically a 7-bit ASCII file**, except for certain elements that may have binary content.

(quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Portable_Document_Format&oldid=742244217#File_structure); emphasis mine)

Of course, in commonly encountered PDF files, these "certain elements" with binary content make up the majority of the file, if only to provide compression of the often large-ish PostScript stuff in the document. (But also for pictures, fonts and other embedded files-in-the-file.)

But if you can forge a reasonably short pure-plain-text PDF that reproduces your problem (I don't know whether that's feasible or even possible in your case) you can simply post its plain text content as a code block.

Comment: "But if you can forge a reasonably short pure-plain-text PDF that reproduces your problem" this is a work for... Latex! (maybe?)

Comment: I was more thinking writing the PDF manually in your favorite text editor while looking at the PDF format specification. Doesn't PDFLaTeX make use of compressed streams in the PDF, too? Posting LaTeX source might be an option if that **reproducibly** produces a PDF file that reproduces(sic!) the problem the question is about, of course.

Comment: `mutool` (shipped with MuPDF) can decompress and ASCII-encode PDF files.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is not too big, you can include it in the post itself.

To avoid encoding problems with binary files, using base64 is a good idea.

For example:

```js
location.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjYNCiWhs8XXDQoxNSAwIG9iag0KPDwvUGFnZUxheW91dC9PbmVDb2x1bW4vUGFnZU1vZGUvVXNlTm9uZS9QYWdlcyAxMiAwIFIgL1R5cGUvQ2F0YWxvZy9NZXRhZGF0YSA4ODggMCBSID4+DQplbmRvYmoNCjE2IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9Bbm5vdHNbIDEzMyAwIFIgIDEzNyAwIFIgIDEzOCAwIFIgIDE0MiAwIFIgIDE0MyAwIFIgIDE0NyAwIFIgIDE0OCAwIFIgIDE1MiAwIFIgIDE1MyAwIFIgIDE1NyAwIFIgIDE1OCAwIFIgIDE2MiAwIFIgIDE2MyAwIFIgIDE2NyAwIFIgIDE2OCAwIFIgIDE3MiAwIFIgIDE3MyAwIFIgIDE3NyAwIFIgIDE3OCAwIFIgIDE4MiAwIFIgIDE4MyAwIFIgIDE4NyAwIFIgIDE4OCAwIFIgIDE5MiAwIFIgIDE5MyAwIFIgIDE5NyAwIFIgIDE5OCAwIFIgIDIwMiAwIFIgIDIwMyAwIFIgIDIwNyAwIFIgIDIwOCAwIFIgIDIxMiAwIFIgIDIxMyAwIFIgIDIxNyAwIFIgIDIyMCAwIFIgIDIyNCAwIFIgIDIyNSAwIFIgIDIyOSAwIFIgIDIzMCAwIFIgIDIzNCAwIFIgIDIzNSAwIFIgIDIzOSAwIFIgIDI0MCAwIFIgIDI0NCAwIFIgIDI0NSAwIFIgIDI0OSAwIFIgIDI1MCAwIFIgIDI1NCAwIFIgIDI1NyAwIFIgIDI2MSAwIFIgIDI2NCAwIFIgIDI2OCAwIFIgIDI2OSAwIFIgIDI3MCAwIFIgIDI3MSAwIFIgIDI3MiAwIFIgIDI3MyAwIFIgIDI3NCAwIFIgIDI3NSAwIFIgIDI3NiAwIFIgIDI3NyAwIFIgIDI4MSAwIFIgIDI4MiAwIFIgIDI4NSAwIFIgIDI4NiAwIFIgIDI5MCAwIFIgIDI5OCAwIFIgIDMwMiAwIFIgIDMwNiAwIFIgIDMwNyAwIFIgIDMwOCAwIFIgIDMxMiAwIFIgIDMxMyAwIFIgIDMxNCAwIFIgIDMxOCAwIFIgIDMxOSAwIFIgIDMyMCAwIFIgIDMyNyAwIFIgIDMzNCAwIFIgIDM5MiAwIFIgIDM5MyAwIFIgIDM5NCAwIFIgIDM5NSAwIFIgIDM5NiAwIFIgIDM5OSAwIFIgIDQwMyAwIFIgIDQwNCAwIFIgIDQwNSAwIFIgIDQwNiAwIFIgIDQwNyAwIFIgIDQwOCAwIFIgIDQwOSAwIFIgIDQxMCAwIFIgIDQxMSAwIFIgIDQxMiAwIFIgIDQxNSAwIFIgIDQxNiAwIFIgIDQyMCAwIFIgIDQyNCAwIFIgIDQyNSAwIFIgIDQyOSAwIFIgIDQzMCAwIFIgIDQzNCAwIFIgIDQzNSAwIFIgIDQzOSAwIFIgIDQ0MCAwIFIgIDQ0NCAwIFIgXS9Db250ZW50cyAxMDcgMCBSIC9Dcm9wQm94WyAwIDAgMjU5MiAxNzI4XS9NZWRpYUJveFsgMCAwIDI1OTIgMTcyOF0vUGFyZW50IDEyIDAgUiAvUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvUHJvY1NldFsvUERGL1RleHRdL1hPYmplY3Q8PC9JbWc5IDEyMCAwIFIgPj4+Pi9Sb3RhdGUgMC9UeXBlL1BhZ2U+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQoxOSAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEgLTQwLjYzOSA0NC40NDkgMV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxODcvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAxMzQgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY+xDoIwEIb3e4obdeBoe21JVwzRxQFp4gsIJgZNYFAf3wPBRElMl96X/+t/7UCjIqd08HLBw1bmB1RgmawNmHAgzwGvwJacM0K0IWabYQvG/CKsoIROnhhOfwaFibHkfbA4h+e5r7GZwsv+RJCojvSo8qS6j/ruSeMT8/3mfw0c4QZ5BPwqkuUMaWUsYxIoOIfxtIyku7q916g1xgZWnKk1xstQJz82mR8coXqkRYRCdinhBeTLRLwNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQoyMCAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTQ1Ljg4MTcgLTU1Ljk4NzEgMjMuOTc2MyAxXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE4Ni9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDEzOSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9j80KwjAQhO/7FHPUQ9Ju/tpcK0UvHrQBX8AqSBX0oD6+21pFESQEMpP9mNkzMXLtc45BHljPRd+oIeWcLksuoLzTsSwYR1JsIFdb6zw6yj8EGlrRWdj+XPb9n3E6hMgwRsciWLz0pcVuHP4NVmIJ6jUPqB1R/0afOVm6o1rO/sfQhk5UJcJXkJST0uw4QEUdvUfa/o5ki7a7tmBG2tHElvkU6TBubIrQM+Ly4NaJaumyogf2+ENBDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC01My4zNzY3IC0zMi44MzAxIDIxLjk4OTMgMV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzUvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAxNDQgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY7BCsIwDIbveYr/qIfWpmHtep0MvXiYK/gCboJMYTuoj2+nE5SB5JI/yceXnhhGZ4aDSw32m5TvVJPKrBbvPJSwzsUwLqTYQjnNkhuHjsxXQE0V9YkdaziNO7baegdrdMiDYIpDg3Y6nWtVGr1AP4I8gfIB345VfKDYrf8p6EBXKiLhR5LeYi3WOIEKOmQZ4nF+sto23a0BM2JLCwlmiXimMlKZnBU9AdkDPYcNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQoyMiAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTIxLjg2OCAtNTUuODAwMSAyMi45NjYxIDFdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTc1L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMTQ5IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nH2PsQrCMBCG93uKf9QhMXdpQrNWii4OtQFfwFaQKrSD+vimWkEpSJb7c/fdl/TEMNoZDj4V2G9SvlNNSozOfQ7lMp0bw7iQYoHyWqxkgo7MV0BNFfUJHc9wGnssOvMOwjr4tHqKQ4N2Gp1bVbp6gWEEZQLtB3w7VvGBYrf+p6ADXamIhB9JehanrwRjoYIOziEe5yOrbdPdGjAjtrSwIV8inqmMVCZnRU+Jij1FDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMjMgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0yNi4xNzk3IC04NS45NjAxIDIzLjM3OTMgMV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzUvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAxNTQgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY67CgJBDEX7fMUttZg4mafTKos2FuqAP+AqyCq4hfr5zq4PFEHS5CY5nJxJoNlrSaE0WM1KvtKalPEsMUWoseMUtOBISgxUYGN1FDSkPwLWtKRzYbtq991ODLsgDsawjcnildsau+fxr1iVUY+mHrVP1L7Rh2eUb5gspv81tKETTTLhS1SeM6zFBweVOHmPvP09Gc3r5lJDBHlHA6f1EPlAVaaqWJd0BzZuPpYNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQoyNCAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEgLTg3LjY1IDM5LjYzOCAxXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE3NC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDE1OSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9jsEOgjAQRO/zFXvUQ0uX0tJeMUQvHpAm/oBgYtAEDurnWxQOSmL2sjOZ2bc9mJQ0ir2NCx22UT9QQztptSPhrLSGrtBaemuiYSXr3GfUIeVfi2pU6OOFcYYzFAlOZZpbmrOTHBpqp+gSLqL1LuZjMZ2Kei5+GEl4UrHf/EPgiBuKAPqCxLdYOuU8CS+9MRROy0Sya7p7Q8wUWqwyxWsKF5QBZURWeAFNsD7ODQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMjUgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0xIC03My41Mzk5IDIyLjk2NSAxXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE3Ni9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDE2NCAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9jsEOgjAQRO/7FXPUQ0u3tECvGKIXD0gTf0AwMWgCB/XzrYASQ2L2sjs7s287YihpFbskNDhsw/ygiphlajKIVEsbO4crsZIu0xZCG2msS9HOEutJQkUldeHGu/ozqXmnWbrE4jP2NZrJu+SLIA1JNyT1mIy/yZES+Sfy/eYvhI50o9wTfjDhM5aZyixDuACx8KelJdrV7b0GM3xDK6P0Gv5ChaciQEt6Ab0AQAMNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQoyNiAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEgLTY4Ljk3IDUxLjcwNyAxXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE3NS9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDE2OSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9js0OgkAMhO99ih71QNnuD+teMUQvHpBNfAHBxKAJHNTHtyKYKInppTOZ6dcOGBU5xSGTBfcb0XeowCnyymOSeQoeL2AsGb8yYpA2bB22oPWvhRWU0MmF1/QnUJiwJpvpgFN40n2NzRie4xOxhmoYqmasmk/1zUnjA/Pd+j8GDnCFPAJ+geQ5TYodCydQcA7jcR5Jt3V7q5EZYwMLq8wS4xmKCIVQS3gC2Y9AAw0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjI3IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMSAtNDIuNTE3IDIzLjEzIDFdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTczL01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMTc0IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nH2OsQ7CMAxEd3/FjTAkjZOmJGtRBQtDaSR+gBYJFaR2AD6fUEoRqoS82GffPXfEUNIq9llssN/E+U4VWeldphxEytLyChdiliqzEDqVxmuHdlJYjwoqKqmLCa/qT6S+O60lG3ymvkYzns7hIkqD0Q1GMxjNZHwzkvBAvlv/Q9CBrpQHwg8kvsUxmSG89NYiHOcHybZubzWYERpamHS1RDhTEaiIxJKe0yo+WA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjI4IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMSAtNjEuNzAyOSAyMy41MjUgMV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzUvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAxNzkgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfU7NDoIwDL73KXrUA2Pt2NiuGKIXD8gSX0A0MWgCB/XxrYgSQ2J6ab9+fx0QamU1BScL7tZy36EGZmXZYuK0yjUHvABp5S17TDhTJhiD7QQRjxDWUEEnHq/pT6CnH5M4WYefu2/wOJLnBRKBBqkfpDxKzVf6zknjA4vt6n8M7OEKRQT8CZJypFzuc6kfVLAW42FOSTdNe2uQCOMRFiYLS4xnKCOUklrBEzoEQFsNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQoyOSAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEyLjQ3OCAtNjEuOTgxMSAyMS44NTkgMV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzgvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAxODQgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY/BDoIwDIbvfYoe9bCyjg23K4boxQOyxBcQTAyawEF9fKugxJCYHbr/X/9+XQeMmpzmkMkF9xvRd6hAMZNdeVSZpuCZ8QKsyZrgUBlLnjOL7WSxGS2soIROhrxOfwI9vRlN3gX8yL7GZuydL6DEkmRK6TvJQzL9JgdKEh+Y79Z/IXCAK+QR8AcjmzEZ5wQSKEiJx3lHsq3bW43y+djAInVmifEMRYRCmCU8AX4xP7cNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQozMCAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEgLTEzLjM5MjYgMjUuMjQ2MSAzOS45NDc0XS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE3NS9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDE4OSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9j7EOgjAQhvd7in/UgdJeW6QrhujigDTxBQQTgyYwqI/viWhMNOaW9u999/V60tBq4YJmaGxXZHClmoKyzBLZXAW3cDiRYWXYwjC611mjQ00V9QI9ajjIsEQebeAM7BS7TPLpPjRox+YfwkQrP5L5SPqJtG/yqUnjDcVm+d9COzpTEQmfHvkayyZBiyao4D3i/qsjXTfdpYExiC3NrMvmiEcqI5XirOgOtaI8lA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjMxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMSAtMTMuMzkzMyAyNS4yNDYgMzEuMTY1OF0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzMvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAxOTQgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY6xDoJADIb3PsU/6sDR690ht2KILg7IJb6AYGLQBAb18T0gJCYa06VN/69fe2Kw2ljPAsZxRxpPqklYsbUwrHTmctxIi9JioAXd0jM61FRRH5mxhku8lcSl8UYgVonNsIxDg3bK/tAlrNwE5hPoZtCMoBnBWZKGF4rD9q+DTnSnIhA+LfEvUX4aEq+8cwjnr0S6b7pHA60RWloZx2uEK5WByqis6A2w7TukDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMzIgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0xIC0xMy43MjUgMjIuMDc4OSA1Mi42MDg4XS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE3NC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDE5OSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9jr0KwkAQhPt9iim1yOb2fpJcGwnaWMQc+AJGQaKQFOrje9EogiJbDcw33/akoDi3XmkobJYkuFJDnnPx2sIJZ6oocCJR7Iy3EI3uHRQ6NFRTH7HxhkOcS0Rzrh20sMoLjykOLfaP6g9hEvciZ1iPnJ448+KeijTcUK4X/wy0pTOVgfDpiE8Jm8xZg8Szdw5h99VIV213aSGCsKeZcTJHOFIVqIrGmu7hJTvVDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMzMgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0yNS4yODI3IC0xNC4yMzg5IDIxLjQzNjMgMjUuNzA2MV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzYvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAyMDQgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY7BDoIwDIbvfYoe9bCxbh2wK4boxQOyxBcQTQyawEF9fAui0ZCYHdq/7ZdvHRAa7Q2FVBrcrSXfoQZlWdvcZig1M7K7gCKLKtUpBfbYgvkKWEMFnaDD60/Djpy2Lg9ojWaXOnznvsHjdDz3KhmNaDaiNKH8QV+eJD6w2K7+a2APVygi4I9IPkfaMBOjCjp4j/EwP0k2TXtrkAjjERbO8xLjGcoIpVgreAIVRD6PDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMzQgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0xIC0xMy43NSAyMiAzMF0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNTgvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAyMDkgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicbY6xDsIwDET3+4obYUgap0pR1qIKFobSSPwALRIqSO0AfD4uZUFFXs723bMHCJ0NTmKhgsed9k80iDbQR94guqV49rNy7NmgxqC+qcYLHI14u1G/Dj5ibNl9PUu2mTBGcus14aliTszULL1YHrZ/oTjhjjKBP1j9QGzuC5poYwhM56Uh27f9o6UIU4dVHsKa6YoqodJTNd5uQjTkDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMzUgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0xIC0xMy43NSAyMS4yNSAyOC4yNV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNjIvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAyMTQgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicdY6xDoIwFEX3+xV31IHaV1IIK4bo4oA08QcEE4MmMKif7yviYIjp0POac+/rAKE13kqRKfC40/mJBmLpcuM8b4pGFMSx/7JlzwY1BrXjGS+wTMSZ3NNZM9mRx5bdrC2XJPqkoTTqTqZQOoc+3ZvwYnnY/qvGCXeUAfwpj18xhRcmhV6e4bwUNvu2f7QUYeiwSn22ZriiCqh0W403cWI3wg0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjM3IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMSAtMTMuMjc2IDIxLjUgNDQuMTI1XS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE2Ni9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDIyMSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx1jrEKwkAQRPv9iim1yGX3zku4NhK0sYg58AdMBIlCUqif7x7GQoJssbMwb2ZHErDxLKFQgeNO7ye1FIw4ZsHGGbEeNxI2usVimCVjQEsNjUqkmS7EyMQaWxawmolZTx362bdsypIxUWWiJFHuS33S8/hCddj+DacT3amKhJ94/UYMqyELJniPeF4a8n03PDqIIPa0cpbXiFeqI9Va19Ab94Y5JQ0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjM4IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMSAtMTMuNSAyMS44NyA2Mi43NV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNjUvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAyMjYgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicbY7BDoJADETv/Yo56oGy3WXRvWKIXjwgm/gDgolBEzion28FY2IwvUybeTPtSWDYGwm5Chy2uj+opsC5RS688riSGM5cFiAW3Xcx6FBTRb0S7xnOZJCIZQ9reL3CKIcG7cc0r0n0pIiDlRFwEzClpvGJYr/5H0pHulERCT+x+oKwVZkEDt4jnuaGdNd09wYiiC0tnJUl4oXKSKV2VfQCt5I3Dg0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjM5IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMSAtMTMuMjggMjAuNzUwMSA1OC43NV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNjcvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAyMzEgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicdY7BDoJADETv/Yo56oGlXbIue8UQvXhANvEHBBODJnBQP98iJMYQ00M7zbxOexKwcSxhowOOO9VPqknYZMIC5413uFEwuXZG951QU0W9+scaLsRIxBqbQ4Iyyk5qaNDOxmVQoqsP5nNYnrFsxqb7aXyhOGz/n6cT3amIhJ+A8SHjWVhVEkxwDvG89KT7pns0EEFsaZXZbI14pTJSqZEVvQEDGDoaDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNDAgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0yMi4zMzMzIC02Ni4zMzAxIDIwLjc3NjcgMV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzMvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAyMzYgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY5BCsIwEEX3c4q/1EXSTNI0ZFspunFRDXgBW0Gq0C7U4zvVCkrBZDN/8h8vPTGM9oZjIQN2a8l32pOyrJ0cqMLLYBgXUmwlanYh5ujIfAXsqaZe2PEOp/GNrbahAEcdQhEwxaFBO1XnWiWrFygErJlA9wHfjiw9UG5X/xR0oCuVifAjGb+lA+dOqirq6D3Scd7JNk13a8CM1NLCWb9EOlOVqBJpTU8bEj3KDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNDEgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0xIC0xMy4yNzYgMzcuMzM5OCAyNC42NjY2XS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE3NS9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDI0MSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9jrEOwjAMRHd/xY0wNI1jmiZrUQULQ2kkfoCChApSOwCfTwrtAJWwF5915+eOGFplmr2NA/abqB9Uk1gl4h2MKBsLVxJWuVsJEqtYnLZoif3vCjVV1MUbQ/dn0kjYKJNbTN5R9g1Oo3WOT+LqHcyj0+gxKFPww0jDE8Vu/Q9BB7pREQhfkOEtlbPjjJF45bMM4Tj3pNumvTdgRjjRQoxdIlyoDFRGaEUvM50/gw0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjQyIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMzIuNjk0MyAtNTQuNTgwMSAyMC4zMzU2IDFdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTc4L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMjQ2IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nH2OPQ7CMAyFd5/CIwxJ4zg/zVpUwcJQGokL0CKhgtQOwPFJaZFAlZAH+9nv6XMPhEpaRcGlAQ/bpB9Qg2CSLhhGYVnaXBFeQZBG4SSxDwY7UF8Ca6igT9mxhvN4Iy21d0hBMtvUJzk02M7WJVak1Tvok1OrOcif4MTI4hOL/eYfAo5wgyIC/kDGt6QJ7HOHIshgLcbT0pPtmu7eIBHGFlaszRrjBcoIZYJW8AIbaj3DDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNDMgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0yNS4xNjY2IC00Mi45MTk5IDIxLjIyMzQgMV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzQvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAyNTEgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY7BCsIwDIbveYoc9dDapF1LrpOhFw9zBV/ATZApbAf18W11gjKQXPIn+fgyAKHRhSHxqcH9JuU7NKDYafLeo3KkhUTwAooYlddkgzjswXwFbKCGIbG5xlPeEWsOHtloZutwimOL3XQ616o0eoEhgzSB9gO+Hav4wHK3/qeAA1yhjIA/kvyWFhu8JIloKQqMx/nNatv2txaJMHawsMxLjGeoIlRJWsMTEi09rA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjQ1IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMSAtNDguNzIgMjUuODU4IDFdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTc1L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMjU4IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nH2Ozw6CMAyH732KHvVAYf/cesUQvXhAlvgCgolBEzioj28RxRgSs8PW3/r1awcKM3KZ4pU8cL+R+g4VeNKBOWBiPXmNF1CarGZMtKXgjcN2SuQeE6yghE4GDKc/Qfb9GygX8FP2NTbv3rk8kUhIQ+ZFupE0Ezla0vjAfLf+K4EDXCGPgD8a2cyQdpZldyZ2DuNx3pJu6/ZWo1IYG1gYq5cYz1BEKERawhP+0z9rDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNDcgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0xIC01Ny40OCA0OC4wNjggMV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzYvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAyNjUgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY6xDoJADIb3PkVHHa7cXbmDWzFEFwfkEl9AMDFoAoP6+FZBEyUxXdo//5evPRjU5LQJXhbcreW+QQ1pRtrnqJynNMczsCOdBVSe2HibYweWfxKsoYJe+OcMR9CojCXPNsOp+z6HBtupO3criYRkMi8yHUn+kKMliXcstqu/EtjDBYoI+KWRzyyxd6n8Hig4h/EwrySbprs2aAzGFhYc3BLjCcoIpUgreACclD8HDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNDggMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIDg5My4wNjcgMTE1My44MiAxMDExLjIyIDEyMTMuMzNdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxL0xlbmd0aCA4Mi9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgLTg5My4wNjcgLTExNTMuODJdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0V4dEdTdGF0ZTw8L0ZPWElUPDwvQUlTIGZhbHNlL0NBIDAuNS9UeXBlL0V4dEdTdGF0ZS9jYSAwLjU+Pj4+L0ZvbnQgNDU1IDAgUiA+Pi9TdWJ0eXBlL0Zvcm0vVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicDcQxDkBAEAXQfk7xTzD+fNZmL0BoJCjcQCJUCte3xXv0RIGuLtdJYh0thM+IubqsGZZj2nG+Vhje5oSIXh5KeCxIeQkixOQUcdtmP9WREN8NCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo0OSAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgNjc1LjI1NSAxMDYyLjA3IDkwOS4yNDUgMTE3MC4zNF0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0Zvcm1UeXBlIDEvTGVuZ3RoIDc5L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAtNjc1LjI1NSAtMTA2Mi4wN10vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRXh0R1N0YXRlPDwvRk9YSVQ8PC9BSVMgZmFsc2UvQ0EgMC41L1R5cGUvRXh0R1N0YXRlL2NhIDAuNT4+Pj4vRm9udCA0NTYgMCBSID4+L1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybS9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3Q+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJxNxDEOQEAQBdD+n+KfYPwxsXYvQGgkKNxAIlQK16dUvCeTRP899/CaD8Txc6Dqpm1Yud8okpXIdE+1KZwXUg5rUtDVyiKLJxa8wQoQuA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjUwIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyA0ODcuMjc4IDExNDkuMTMgODgzLjY1MSAxMjQ5LjEzXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvRm9ybVR5cGUgMS9MZW5ndGggMTMyL01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAtNDg3LjI3OCAtMTE0OS4xM10vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRXh0R1N0YXRlPDwvRk9YSVQ8PC9BSVMgZmFsc2UvQ0EgMC41L1R5cGUvRXh0R1N0YXRlL2NhIDAuNT4+Pj4vRm9udCA0NTcgMCBSID4+L1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybS9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3Q+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJxNzbkNQkEMBNDcVbiCwetj7d8ACBIkIKADJAQRAe2z/wgI7ODNWBaICLe/fTlQU/6S8GnMk3b78/1448eHfApEdW7qglLhN5UGNGqlLOEXlY3QtlbISo7oNsgm2Naa0DRmyuXtIFdYLmTIWKkjcz7UDtGFMmDu3Fok3GrQlX44uCb3DQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNTEgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIDM3Ny43NzggMTE4OC4wMSA1MDMuNzMgMTI0OS4xNF0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0Zvcm1UeXBlIDEvTGVuZ3RoIDExOS9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgLTM3Ny43NzggLTExODguMDFdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0V4dEdTdGF0ZTw8L0ZPWElUPDwvQUlTIGZhbHNlL0NBIDAuNS9UeXBlL0V4dEdTdGF0ZS9jYSAwLjU+Pj4+L0ZvbnQgNDU4IDAgUiA+Pi9TdWJ0eXBlL0Zvcm0vVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicTcu7DYJBDAPgPlNkgpDX5ZIF+AUNElCwARKCioL1uYiGwi4+2ULMjPzX5w1E8QOMx5UH7Pan2+GK9zdYBnEGilSQKeMLXIpyFIoaU3DhE1yTzL1pkg9rMiOe2bTmJU3uNMIWOVNqNtUgV/3RrD5e4Av8GB+jDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNTIgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0xIC00OC41IDMxIDFdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTUzL01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMjc4IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nG2NuwrCQBRE+/mKKbXIus+s20aCNhYxC/6AqyBRSAr1812SCIJ2M9w55/aQlMLbIDUlD1soPtFCWeEdC+uF4w0qR22F9iW7sSg9FbZo0P9TFFJMO593RlGZkRjSjKzii9V+k9GPzEjOaUg44o4qgt/m4QIn1rpkEURwjvH0c1/tUvdIVIrxjIUJdsl4RR1R51cN3sHjMBUNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo1MyAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTMzIC0yNS41IDMzIDc0LjVdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTY2L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMjgzIDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nG2NsQ7CMAxEd3/FjWVI6iR1QteiChYGaCR+gIKEClI7AJ+PCyxISJbudH4+j8Rgm6qaPRj7NTk8qNMwBSu4qnEBwywY0NGOxn8HJniljRdEgRf1U/+ly/xEs13NiAKVrmKFt049HehGTf5pnM5kvLMVR5ja1iLIRyo3/XDv4RzyiYrEIjGmBfJFay3LEsZ561Oc2SKUXof5A7SZWn2/oxdr1S+KDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNTQgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0zMy41Njk1IC0xMy4zOTM3IDIyLjcyOTUgMzIuNjE2M10vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzUvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAyODcgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY+xDoIwEIb3e4p/1IHSa22xK4bo4oA08QVEE4MmMKiP74GoMSSmy137f/3uWmJo5TQHLwV2a+nvVFFijXI+OFhWnr3FhRI2SLySZEBD+lujopJaAfvTnfonNsoGm8Gwyoz88u67GscxPLUmcjWgywE1I2o/6MuTxgfy7eq/hvZ0pTwSfkQynKwTdCaeoIJziIdpJN3Uza0GM+KRZnah54hnKiIVYi3pCbRlPk8NCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo1NyAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEgLTE0LjIzOTMgMjIuODk2IDY3Ljk3NTddL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTc0L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMjk5IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nH2OuwrCQBBF+/mKW2qRzc4+kt02ErSxiFnwB0wEiUJSqJ/vGmNAAjLN3OEezvTEkMJK9llccNjG/KCaFAvnM2SZ8LnNcSWWwihvwArdHCQ61FRRH6n3DGeSSFgLpb2GksJZ5/HNQ4N2Ki+VSTyNaD6iPKFmRj+eNDxR7Df/NXSkGxWB8COKz7FQ1hqDxAtvLcJpWUl3TXdvwIzQ0kobt0a4UBmojNaKXgtaPcANCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo1OCAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEuMjg3ODQgLTEzLjM5MjQgMjMuMTI5MiA2MS4yMDI2XS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE3NC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDMwMyAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9jkEKwkAMRfc5xV/qouMk0xk720rRjYvqgBewClIFXajHN9ZakIJk8z/k5eVKDGu85Rg0YLPU/qAtZdZIMS9yQdBkJeBMzMaGPIAF7VAsWmyppquC77kdySJjMS5KDhHDEgXffmtw6JfHVnX6Di061PWoG9CPZ5aeKNeL/xra0YXKRPgR6XOs162WLJroPdJ+vDJbNe29ATPSgSbOuynSiapElVpregGEnD4MDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNTkgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIDY4Ny41NTMgMTIyMy4zMyA3MTguOTE3IDEyNTcuMDhdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxL0xlbmd0aCAxMDMvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIC02ODcuNTUzIC0xMjIzLjMzXS9TdWJ0eXBlL0Zvcm0vVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0L1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgNDYwIDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nG3KOw6EMBAD0N6nmBOMPPlN0m6DRAmHAKHdhobrk4hyKWxZT6aSFKqn1nvsZQL/8NzgcoEy9xxwFm1mYiFRQ3H5obSszPGhFFy+WOFmmswHNs3V3n/jZWVQpNYYO+344AYMcR3SDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNjAgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0xMy44OTMyIC0xNi4yNTI0IDEzLjg5MzIgMF0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxMTYvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCAzMDkgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicK+TSD6lQcPJ15tI1NNazsDQ2UtA1NNMzMjUyUTAy1zO3MDNRgPGLUrnCufK4nEK4FAwUDPTMTSwNjICsonSgXiM9C2MLBRBtZq4QkoKhQt8jNacsVcHQRCEkjUvDxcBQUyEki8s1hMsVaHUgFwBzAxxmDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNjEgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIDc4NC4zNjEgMTEwNS41OCA4MTcuODg0IDExMzguMDddL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxL0xlbmd0aCAxMDUvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIC03ODQuMzYxIC0xMTA1LjU4XS9TdWJ0eXBlL0Zvcm0vVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0L1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgNDYxIDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nG2MPQ7CUAyD95wiJ7Ccvp/krV2QGOEQVFW7sHB98ljLYMv6ZJsgqYTXkT7z4ya8wPdLXD9Cvad2CRqaVzWzAV9CT/FhiG4TNYxoesgzewW9TliYg+V/L4wo8XsroPdEm6zyBRMpHfANCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo2MiAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEyLjkyNDUgLTE1LjcxMzcgMTIuOTI0NiAwXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDExNC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDMxNSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJwr5NIPqVBw8nXm0jU00rM0MjFV0DU01TM3NDZXMDLVszCxNFSA8YtSucK58ricQrgUDBQM9MxNLA2MgKyidLBeC2MLBRBtZq4QkoKhQt8jNacsVcHQRCEkjUvD2cBQUyEki8s1hMsVaHUgFwByqhxlDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KNjMgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIDQzMC42ODUgNzQwLjI0NSA0NTguNzk5IDc3MC42Ml0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0Zvcm1UeXBlIDEvTGVuZ3RoIDk3L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAtNDMwLjY4NSAtNzQwLjI0NV0vU3VidHlwZS9Gb3JtL1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDQ2MiAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJxtirENhEAMBPOtwhVYC2efuZQEiRCKACFISGifI+GDJ9jVaDRUkkINK/UfngbwT54LslygjHUbzBplFAl3tZTkgHmrtJ/ZMcNSVHYJy1qKf1Zvk5N2wWpW9LgBgTodDg0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjY0IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMTMuMDUwOCAtMTUuODg3OSAxMy4wNTA4IDBdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTE2L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMzIxIDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nCvk0g+pUHDydebSNTTWMzA1sFDQNTTVs7Awt1QwMtMzNDA0U4Dxi1K5wrnyuJxCuBQMFAz0zE0sDYyArKJ0oF4jPQtjkFYjPTNzhZAUDBX6Hqk5ZakKhiYKIWlcGs4GhpoKIVlcriFcrkCrA7kAdcccbg0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjY1IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMTIuOTExMyAtMTUuNjYyOSAxMi45MTEzIDBdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTE0L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMzI4IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nCvk0g+pUHDydebSNTTSszQ0NFbQNTTVMzMzslQwMtWzMDIyU4Dxi1K5wrnyuJxCuBQMFAz0zE0sDYyArKJ0sF4LYwsFEG1mrhCSgqFC3yM1pyxVwdBEISSNS8PZwEhTISSLyzWEyxVodSAXAHJPHGYNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo2NiAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEyLjkxMTMgLTE1LjY2MjkgMTIuOTExMyAwXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDExNC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDMzNSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJwr5NIPqVBw8nXm0jU00rM0NDRW0DU01TMzM7JUMDLVszAyMlOA8YtSucK58ricQrgUDBQM9MxNLA2MgKyidLBeC2MLBRBtZq4QkoKhQt8jNacsVcHQRCEkjUvD2cBYUyEki8s1hMsVaHUgFwByXhxnDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KOTAgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIDM4My42MjkgNzQzLjczNCA0NzYuOTM1IDc2Ni40NzhdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxL0xlbmd0aCA3OC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgLTM4My42MjkgLTc0My43MzRdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0V4dEdTdGF0ZTw8L0ZPWElUPDwvQUlTIGZhbHNlL0NBIDAuNS9UeXBlL0V4dEdTdGF0ZS9jYSAwLjU+Pj4+L0ZvbnQgNDY0IDAgUiA+Pi9TdWJ0eXBlL0Zvcm0vVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicM9AzMDBQMEQig9y5DI0UyrkMFLyAOItL380/wjNEIb2Yy8TMVM/MwlTB3NREz9LCRCGXy9jSRM/C3BIoYqpnZGShkMMVzAUApAEQhw0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjkxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyA0NTQuNTQ0IDc0My42OTggMTAyNC42OSA4NTYuOTE3XS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvRm9ybVR5cGUgMS9MZW5ndGggMTAzL01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAtNDU0LjU0NCAtNzQzLjY5OF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRXh0R1N0YXRlPDwvRk9YSVQ8PC9BSVMgZmFsc2UvQ0EgMC41L1R5cGUvRXh0R1N0YXRlL2NhIDAuNT4+Pj4vRm9udCA0NjUgMCBSID4+L1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybS9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3Q+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJxNyzEOgzAMheHdp/AJjJ0+x8kFQHRBgg69QaUKpg69PolYGN4/fNIzUVXWW9eJLPGflJ9tXxrG5T2/+PMjZJeo4HBIReGDwlVS6eLt67xTgQpqcIFLtmhiag8BcFHutNEJjzoXug0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjkyIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMSAtMjUuMzQzNiA5NS42Mzk2IDM1LjIyNjJdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMjAxL01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgMzk3IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nH2PwW4CMQxE7/6KOdJDvI6TOJsrFWovPQCR+gNdkBCtBIe2n9+wWxCCqrIvtmb8xgcSCOdYRCFYPZHHF62pRLZQDCGyqineKRuXHDOcV/bZ99iTxdsV1rSkQ7txquO23XYaOcRgsDCJz/NxwGYU/8F3wml09qPzF6Pp4pwwXf3G/OXxfwq90gfNK+Ga06L5xuh9hCtcUkJ9u1N0z8P+c4D3qBuaZUnJLD+g7sgFltSPf2u2k3cWOm0tMgkWlRYt2JJ+AE84RzkNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo5MyAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEgLTEzLjM5MzYgNDYuOTg4IDM5LjI1MjRdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTc1L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgNDAwIDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nH2OuwrCQBBF+/mKW2qx475m3W0jQRsLdcEfMAoShaRQP98YH4iKTDXDPfdMQxqaxz5pC43llAzOtCIvnGKEi2zFehzIBbZeLFRgk8I4oibrP09Y0YKaruI27a6rVsaySy7gGX7ubYVtH/6hV5qlJ2NPyoN0L/KuGeULivnkv4XWdKQiE9493WuWk4+SoBInEeTNV2I0q+pTBWOQtzRwXobIeyozlZ1zQVc8Xz+aDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KOTQgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIDYyOC4yNTQgNzgzLjEwNCA2NDAuMjU0IDEwMTkuNzldL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxL0xlbmd0aCA3Ny9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgLTYyOC4yNTQgLTc4My4xMDRdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0V4dEdTdGF0ZTw8L0ZPWElUPDwvQUlTIGZhbHNlL0NBIDAuNS9UeXBlL0V4dEdTdGF0ZS9jYSAwLjU+Pj4+L0ZvbnQgNDY2IDAgUiA+Pi9TdWJ0eXBlL0Zvcm0vVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicM9AzNTBSMNAzMjUEkgYGBgpB7lwmCuVcBgpeQJzFpe/mH+EZopBezGVmbAJUZqJgaGBoomdqbK6QCxcyt7DQMwbSOVzBXAClMxBxDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KOTUgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIDYyOC4yMTYgNzU1LjUzIDY0MC4yMTYgNzkzLjY3MV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0Zvcm1UeXBlIDEvTGVuZ3RoIDcwL01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAtNjI4LjIxNiAtNzU1LjUzXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9FeHRHU3RhdGU8PC9GT1hJVDw8L0FJUyBmYWxzZS9DQSAwLjUvVHlwZS9FeHRHU3RhdGUvY2EgMC41Pj4+Pi9Gb250IDQ2NyAwIFIgPj4vU3VidHlwZS9Gb3JtL1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdD4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nDPUMzAwUDBAIoPcuUwUyrkMFLyAOItL380/wjNEIb2Yy8zYRM/I0EzB3MJCz8TIUCEXIWJmoGduYaCQwxXMBQCRbxAxDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KOTYgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIDY5Mi40OTQgNzU1LjA4MSA3MDQuNDk0IDc5My4yMjJdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxL0xlbmd0aCA3MC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgLTY5Mi40OTQgLTc1NS4wODFdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0V4dEdTdGF0ZTw8L0ZPWElUPDwvQUlTIGZhbHNlL0NBIDAuNS9UeXBlL0V4dEdTdGF0ZS9jYSAwLjU+Pj4+L0ZvbnQgNDY4IDAgUiA+Pi9TdWJ0eXBlL0Zvcm0vVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicM9QzMDBQMEAig9y5TBTKuQwUvIA4i0vfzT/CM0QhvZjLzNJCz8TSRMHcwlzP0txIIRchYmagZ2xsqJDDFcwFAJXdEFcNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo5NyAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgNjM1LjMwNSA3ODIuNzMyIDcwMy41NjIgMTAxOS4yNV0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0Zvcm1UeXBlIDEvTGVuZ3RoIDEwMC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgLTYzNS4zMDUgLTc4Mi43MzJdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0V4dEdTdGF0ZTw8L0ZPWElUPDwvQUlTIGZhbHNlL0NBIDAuNS9UeXBlL0V4dEdTdGF0ZS9jYSAwLjU+Pj4+L0ZvbnQgNDY5IDAgUiA+Pi9TdWJ0eXBlL0Zvcm0vVHlwZS9YT2JqZWN0Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicTcq7DYRQDETR3FW4AjM2z+/TwCJIkICADpBWS0RA+1hEG8wNjgbiMIaYaxQALwMlvgk8xb7UfeZ93Pi4KCeIu7NC0/s8g1R6zVxaEc3gH+VWQ+wVWPmXWqRVC1npAXY9F4INCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo5OCAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgMTcwMS44IDEyMTguNTUgMTcyNC40IDEyNDIuMTddL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxL0xlbmd0aCAxMDYvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIC0xNzAxLjggLTEyMTguNTVdL1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybS9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCA0NzAgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicdY0xDoQwDAR7v8IvsNZ2QkhLcxIlPAKEQkNz3z8HSnSFV6vZkQwBwJCSamTvy4fwgtdGib8EnuMO0qJVNFY1h3g2PoOhCFJ5WNbKjdZujpLhnQ5SLf0xb89Ng5nLGC8b7TTRD6IkHsANCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQo5OSAwIG9iag0KPDwvQkJveFsgLTEzLjA4NSAtMTUuNzM2IDEzLjA4NSAwXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDExNC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDQxMyAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJwr5NIPqVBw8nXm0jU01jOwMFXQNTTVMzc2UzAy0zM0s7RUgHKLUrnCufK4nEK4FAwUDPTMTSwNjICsonSgRiM9C2MLBRBtZq4QkoKhQt8jNacsVcHQRCEkjUvDycBUUyEki8s1hMsVaG8gFwAiuBvSDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMTAwIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMzYuMjUgLTgzLjc1IDIzIDFdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTYwL01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgNDE3IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nGWNsQ7CMAxE9/uKG2FI2iSkNGtRBQtDaSR+gBYJFaR2AD4fR3SBytLpbD+fRxjm2ucmFGJ42kv/QgvlvLaeqrR663mHMo6q0J6D2NmxRYNRDlJNV+RMlLUUnTr283YZr2SUWFHraDaJ/mZl8c3quPuLwhkPVBH8CZOPRpe2oAo6eM94WQLZoRueHY1h7LFyIawZb6gjannS4AP74jN5DQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMTAxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtNTUuMzE0OSAtMzEuMjYgMjIuNTExMSAxXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE3NC9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDQyMSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9jsEKwjAQRO/zFXvUQ2I2aaK5VopePNQG/AFbQarQHtTPd6tFlILksJnZmbx0YDLaG45BLrTfiL6jgvKZdpxFUs5oG+gCxZZUEHNpLLUwX4IqlOikOZz+NOzY6uBcJMvaM4s/6r6mZgxPsUosqTrNr6odq+5TfXMW6UH5bv0fgwOuyBPoBySfk+SKvXCijjLScRpZbOv2VpO8lxrMXOQ5pTOKhEKoJZ6hkj4eDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMTAyIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMjIuOSAtNDMuOTUwMSAyMS4yIDFdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTY5L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgNDI2IDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nG1PMQ7CMAzc/YobYUjqJG1Q1qIKFobSSHyAFAkVpHYAno/bMoCKvNzZvju7JwPWBZvgBeC4E/6khpQ1OkDlVgcZ4kbKOCivLTNv0An9Ymiopl6UYw0XYihjdQ7L2mJCQ0L72VmmKWlNigBJFYWbFbNrFl8oD9u/pnSiO5WR8GM7XqCD9cweKsgDBeJ5uZPtU/dIMAaxpZULbo14pSpSJWk1vQGYmji/DQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMTAzIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtNDguNjg1NSAtMzcuMDkgMjEuOTg4NSAxXS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvTGVuZ3RoIDE3Ni9NYXRyaXhbIDEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9SZXNvdXJjZXM8PC9Gb250IDQzMSAwIFIgPj4+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJx9j0EKwjAQRfdzir/URaaZxMRmWym6cVENeAFbQarQLtTjm2oVRZBs8mf+4yUdCTQ7LcGnCzbLlK+0JTWbs8+dg7KedcCJlBgoz1acBLSkPwK2VFGXyOH0h2Enhr3VBkZzyHOHV+5rNGP5V6vSKKGW5YHKiNo3+vRk8YZivfivoR2dqYiEL1F6nLA12niowCH9L+5/K9mqbi81RBAbmthgpohHKiOVyVrRHb3oPjMNCmVuZHN0cmVhbQ0KZW5kb2JqDQoxMDQgMCBvYmoNCjw8L0JCb3hbIC0xOS44OTQ3IC0xMy43ODQ0IDI1LjA2MzMgMjMuMzk1OF0vRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0xlbmd0aCAxNzYvTWF0cml4WyAxIDAgMCAxIDAgMF0vUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRm9udCA0MzYgMCBSID4+Pj5zdHJlYW0NCnicfY6xDoJADIb3PkVHHTiuvTu4WzFEFwfkEl9AMDFoAoP6+BZFoyExXfq3/fK1B0KtnKaQSYO7teQb1JCQVz7YHJmVCc7jWUaMSSaJmbAD/RWwhgp6QccajuOOWOXeWmSrdGYMvvPQYDsdz72JjAQ1ip+om1DzQV+eNN6x2K7+a2APFygi4I9InmPlXZ6JJ6jgHMbD/CTdNN21QSKMLSyMpSXGE5QRSrFW8AAbuT6aDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMTA1IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9CQm94WyAtMzcuOTc2OCAtMTMuMzk4MSAyNS4wNjQyIDguMjMxOTNdL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9MZW5ndGggMTc4L01hdHJpeFsgMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL1Jlc291cmNlczw8L0ZvbnQgNDQxIDAgUiA+Pj4+c3RyZWFtDQp4nH2Ouw7CMAxFd3/FHWGIG+fR1isIwcIAjcQPUJAQIMEAfD4hPBYQ8mLL9/j4RBaWm6DWwWI5JcGVOjK+Zm3qFg07L+pxICMOpmZRFewz9enR0YJOGXzUeftYiWOvrcAFtnVweM/nHpsS/iE1lmMh20LGF+k/5FNTpRtG8/F/C63oSKNEKJ7oNEhu82/5eswJo6wxIq2/E9Ws3196iCBtaOCDHyLtaJJokqULugP3kT2sDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KMTA3IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9MZW5ndGggMzkvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj5zdHJlYW0NCnicK1QwMjQzUABBQ1M9YzMQF8hOzlXQ98xNt1RwyVcI5AIAkHkIBA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjEyMCAwIG9iag0KPDwvQml0c1BlckNvbXBvbmVudCA4L0NvbG9yU3BhY2UvRGV2aWNlUkdCL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9IZWlnaHQgMzIvTGVuZ3RoIDQ5Mi9TdWJ0eXBlL0ltYWdlL1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9XaWR0aCA1MDQwPj5zdHJlYW0NCnja7cExAQAAAMKg/qlnCj+gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgJcBWJMMVg0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjg4OSAwIG9iag0KPDwvVHlwZSAvT2JqU3RtIC9OIDIwMC9GaXJzdCAxOTUzL0xlbmd0aCA4NDM2L0ZpbHRlciAvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGU+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJztXWtz3caR/SsopSqRqgLceT8UWyk9ok1qHa83ViUfbH3AU2KKIlXkVWzn1+85A9xLgAQpiLxriw4sg3cGj8FguvtMd0/PjFSZyKTOdMikMpmSFr+OaZzQGkdgAld0lEjYTBneq12mrOSjHongeWOmvOM9MdPeohwjUKxQSEgkvEFCZTpa3GN0ZqTiJZOZaPG4sUhEFGhcZoXjJZ9ZFiZRFasln4qZYxnSCiQ8XoGynMKN0qrMaXyAtDpzJqKG1mRea95jkXA84zJvUCmJ93kr+VTIvON32ZgFq1GyE0g4PIUvCQ4fJ1GV4CVKdjoLga3hTBa9QtvgvuhRqnQui0Hxks/wEXwcGSE8au9wiKjwEi+YQr2kR04KtrPHO5FEYR6HVPwotpRCOkufqNg00pMminX2nqnIUhLNWD7fozXIKANJotGGMpAURuKeoJiKKCWQoM7xKqlhBf4GUsryS4Nj6wuURXoaxzy/1wSSNUS2YMS5mJpQIZ+aLgj8jaRKYI0iG0aAHpJ1dIHv5LvRznyWrRVZauS3CDY1qYX2ZHl8t8D3KyH4BQLMxdIDv1CRlYJCeyu2VzBaIGX4brSnYqtHLfgs36M97/OsBVhCCb7RKZbHkgzaXsn0PEiPxubzGn/R6ngedyvJpzzaDgSgXKC+lA4FPhD8i8MLXuV5z/opno98G6itlA88hztUSH95PqBNFOVMRdZZoTxNjlesj46sM+toBGsJhkIq8D7kDLlV8d1Gg1MVa2vJr4o5y3ZXEFhllWOpeIfVhvchZ8ntijLrtGEpnimWTKl1qYXQ/ngylY/DebYkBBccaVgjxVRIb6ecg74Ksqu8T3XDO3wEVRS/BaKOv3wqpHbhG0OAqCoIMJqA3wUJVlGKVHOkokk1Z4ptgPpoIfgcpEULyXaC0GqhYoKbDHCQvjAy5fg1wBrZfwPARmrSB3KKxgWPskU0GgfvAO8j5XgV5SUsU5BVjWrgHZAljSzKg6xqvI6YhvI0+VtBVgEopDJkVQNS2Dp4h5HgOEou2hsloHWQcqQCZBXtzRaCZGjrWD+0CFIoS6E1tfVsRZSkbSDXgN+0jZAXBbnBKzzbzjDFL4esahcpH5BN7WVqWbzDR9YFUgW8JbeC85DCPSoSgwldKvKq5vdCygDmbDFIGVKRrY0axNROghhNztGgpxF8llKFFGRXQ8qMSC2GbzZCGz7hkSJEasgNGJZfCP41IAwpIJDyuIcQbpKkgFJIAWdJqcwoygEohRTqgBTeoYk8pKLRlCYN/kWKNQWiQQBIH4l3aK9JPbxDE3c17jUmoL54jCnwFOidGRvYJpA84KUiD+AdXuALQW+k2KNoSJ7x5DANuqOQyFLwjpD6LUgGeIm1h+RZQQSgHCLFWoG3gKbs8cCXVrBHZOeDDiwkXkEK34QUOjUICeqs2atZ1hlcYUl+8IpAihLFdrDoM132xReb56cfTraZ3Pz3UXP+HeATPfbfstebVz+9bzfflG/a8ydPeNdZW26PTk9elNv24YvHwE0QQQr0I8baXITfCfG7R5u/njYXNwDr8S/gtW5/wzdnp82Huj172Jx+8+Jl9vf2LPOFzp59ODpuyErZ9w//cXTSnP5wnnmcPT86ac/Psz81R3w3Ln77TSa/f5TlfPIcpx5nrpCFd4JP/ujM94++f/QoVfhZed6+PD3Zbp6eHZXHmz+d1KfN0cmbDYp/enJ+tM+/PDo73z5/W56BGhs+8KI9r8+O3m9Pz5KuwtbYfFUO9wDrNt9+qLZsnFdnH9rUSulPetc/jprtW7QiBbIXShAJjMiDLOKcT90aCZoOnLPB9PcSQIbnds987NjfjzL2B1UGAS7ny3h48CqPlIeUeDzAfHoQMsrzqYKoQLoX59Nzw33754Z0BKbsyub5XSV4UF9gWYljdxXFO8YV3qdTv6XSdf6G8TPD0XO+uHgOaT88szsoEwmhdd8A3vbv428qfygHGpOYFJxO8Cv2GZ9UP5l+d4/z2NNrKDrdfFHmkGHDpJcPxe6oeoVqTuzr4DUBdqgXoXg4ZwEthmWbePF2lgWhpTo1PqedHQho9ge/Yk+kS0f/qTvKjo4xJdVA/R1HXD5SS4/vGXPZwBnXsS1FYcwVl9l5kRgkdX3mHbtyhXidgODped0S4IRwm+fl+z+3R2/ebnl5Q0nnpRx4vXl5XL4532HAs2enP36X5exleZEKo0glvE6Xvy7ftQOu/GVbHh/VT0/eHLeZ2Hy7bd/9Hb97RLgAk74u3+DP14CABCtPnmyefYsT/8gkks8Bvvz3evP8KeD4+VffwebQhUcf5gNAEn0DjJECymqGLqNwQH4n1TiPJ/FKfNH5Q7DU92fowh/NAzcUPSjHUu1x+cXTh1mGt4vCsieWrN9/bf7cHv+rhd2QveouXTx7gz+varZJ9urfTB+jkG8fdqjA4yw9tz2qSzxbCPF++4f69Pj07PFvXr5EQ4pHm5eZ2fzl1eblWdu+an/cPi+Pj08/bDdf/em7zdenJ23683rz110/EiAxEXbTRUfz9V8fRugRXVWGvLNNl5u6q/ISVlYOhUj5qhZQQxU6nF2Ptvnm9P2H98miTNn/RRv/7fnDL/7447vj7F99b/LlA1T3wR+ffFGdNj9luHBy/uWDt9vt+8ebzQ8//FD8oIvTszcbGBJx8+Pb7bvjB/1Nj3/sysmNyKc7z+u37btyg2zelNtyg+I3eKYrHz/95i9/3730aX12WpXbx2wsvD9dP3/f1l8+UDihHjz54n3WHJ19+eB4e/YgO9/+dNx++WCLdsvBe29OHpOJ2zPcdv6+PNldJyXy86N/tygWBOizvPT45PTsXXncn/khScPj6vS4uaBRAI36y1357uj4p8eJ1R88AVP99jc/iqd/+GLDNz35YvP+86maHFdqQwI+ebT524vv6IAwRaRpqUQREvu+3vytrbffAcNiQT3eB9fLlzZJ3mBsF0IG3Ha6hdhQsD9U/3w4sOmjvQaw49/Nq4ePepl/enJyuu1FHRVLTo/EbZSI5N/Y59rk5ehhYKyu7GXnepVlr4Dgj7zAmmvKyZ+hBW9X2Evo+jsppLoHYwjqvB5LoRW+kbUs8+C8y03VuDyUQecqtNp3ojRtDSn8n/ftSdaVx+ftWCDLswTM6MFSvqeJoqPEeVk4mpbOgXboWBzkwL7eVzbJ8pUW78EV2voycI2hcMB2EB89rgS2+UR4WKmZN3qcHwNrILCGzw9Yw+2BFZbKmKRVFFVrrMphgovclG3MY9X6vKosjLNGu65pZoDVqBVYb4te4fMF1nAtsBooI9Q+tChoNosLXHXRD6KFw/nCQFcJRhYx+INjqhETTDVyxdRtcpdfxdRQ6DDGVL8QUOUyQA3oSaWMFsidRWHQoyZfsizw8ijdOD8G1ChuwFIplLlnWDohpaiayjsXch+NzE1riaVC5kGH0ldS6FK4OSxdldRbA1YU1wGWVeDB5IEprE1AsUes4Dg+Ek3iXQ1BcWlEJBTG3QmxBoya6n1m1fuIUWaq9xkOVglpi+Q0FwmjpBRmIUipZSBFvwp6EHBAZqFUBo6kKWiCUPasV+P8BKPCrwuj/JiUjRamkZ3Luzq2OfrqNq9k0+bRdrGVTrdt7GYwyq763u0xKlyHUarnSQOo0nYCUZYj28oEci46WTr5wIEQlwMAlJ0qUXZVohJAhasAJZWG1nsBUEqqYqlhqpdBlAmiSEPzCaVM1AUHvTU6I0VnuB1lRxhlxOemRwnx7OXtMUq6MTVN2Wjjrclj6DT0qKhhjoomRzceXSXqSsU5Z59d9ajbYhT46VqMsoX0kQNLhYFJNwYp4+PAuwmnVCw4ViuBZYfRpOxUk7KrJkWgsjOalARATIHKLwYqsxCooEC5EHqkwq+xrhAMw9F0CcTMGDPOT8DqJgfa/VOoZBxTtGx1a7yOedOZmJumDXnZqjp3rfPQqTQDB2bAyq0K1e3B6gb3v6crgsFiheMA5QVWKXzVgFXkXid7btYaknIIrcpNtSq3alUJrOa0KgDEFKziYrCyC8FKm+STZEwjrXyjocjRyI8c89lntXDITqBK/aqgSqkJPSsP8w7w5ZSWuSllyKMKFazAWFWtFbEOcQ6qVr3q9lClrocqdKiCMc1iilIheU5N8qwa/ARGKWuYivJu/vQBpqY6lVt1KsKUm9OpGG8xhikhF8OUWwhTIhYywRQgkZHzURU+JpwiHzDwcpyfAJX+NQEV8WhEUS07B8K1udXG5gwIzaNvZV55YUwZo4hdNQNUftWpbg9U+nqgspbj44wKLjRjhPdwpa0v0rQABduP4bdSDPwckT8AWvmpUuVXpSqh1YxSBSGa+tLDUl+6X+hLd6HwmuEz0N6MyayHDsVwteiLiBrt8gGYhvzYoW78DVhl1X1zVqmJ/ac70ZpW+byKsc6NAkwFH02udajKyoHIPsxh1apU3dqhbvz1WEUgUmaiVFnYet4wkDX2nBugVPmQBaUL7Q4CU1Olyq9KFWHKXwr1Mj5D/104zj5xoAXDEiJIIPVCpAoLY70cytY9vTkpx9lQcLJOkDbxwT6vPPMTpIo3IZWR9l5pVX5K0lJUDWjncg9yA6lCAEl1yFtT+c5KGIDdnKcqrFrV7ZEqXo9UJtBdjrZGtxkNHSX7iCrjoFZpRtz3DOxFYmhGVUlzCMAKU70qrHpVAqxwBbAY3NbHUQ2AFdxCsFoa9R9UYROlOX+N+GhESDH+hvMtdnnlmB9Dlb3JU/VLQNXdlCo9iVIofSebsqpyYUMDYrY6L7sAG9HXXW1N6+VslEJYlapbQ5W91lOFqpMXgVfSmckAoAsyMa/vmVcyUMEDpvBh0RwCpqZ6VVj1KsJUmNGrGEnC6WsDTNEIQ8+xDKr0whh6GzSpbXRyrVtOoxASVOdQS7jIU8WbQpVxN0GVNZehiiwGzSwm3+hlqJpc/EW0KjMJoG+7Wsm2jrmpBQgq2zIvVWXyzljYhbAAG9fOQFVctaqboarvTua1Kne9VsV/OhTReLO3/7wu2Le7KAtOe7cRwqEMF/AgJx8Ap+JUnYqrOpVwaqpOpVn02vZTfYxNbiqrzOKpPnphZLrzljClGU/lnC+sj8BHWXDG8D4PfER+ok/dFFF1D0FqQs0gXNW0voIW5cvcGOvy6JTIyxgaravWymrO9IurPnVrkLLXRlQNICWgTtmwV6UgECALQMoCvCRUKzAQ2Ae9TXEQiJqqUnFVpQhRUR8WohbGpdPo05G6lC1oZEKx4npAXkCBdnKfd5FhCnKCUjeFUv0SKHU3q89MrL4QS+N0qXIbLaw+AlTw3uZd0AEMAPwy5VWUUmJVpW6PUjeEUvGflQWIdYFSnKrrXUInzmh2jKfhomj0WB0gPIFrdY1gigt2rTCVVjW7ClOxEHKEUr7XZRfB1MLYdFLVU0+mGxL2vcUrFe18X0hB/7oc5ycwZT4Npj5zP7qdTvNryq6upcitVjD70FnklQ0BFl/TdFXnfWP1HEytytTtnVPm2vB09M4hjWFzPbmC8/F3YMXelexLXwhsER9VwRX60OGRnQ8BVnYKVqtOBbDigopXwIqUcBdgpRmkuxSsFsanM5LOB49fDpyI/tdOUcn+ulBpojz5JtrYxCqvu4YucxPyKmiT+7pqVQu1qnYzwZ1cpHJFpduikr1ZeVJxD0UxOcoNTYk0uMPlEu625EwPQXKqL8lVX0oQNKMvBTPRl7z6BH1pYdR5oL5kGVeQkoFpMDF/hqyPnDE1waRP9I1/3pgUxCQ2SuiuFU0UeeSqM6YD61Rl7CBHrema0itPr9tVTFo1pdtj0kd847ATksu7XwhBW3InF0UKlqPMB4GkqVYkV62IkCSvakVWM2j2wtPkGI+0FJIWRm3KIGC8cRFwAWjgItzQhvkrXUzn93mG8k4c4uoGh3iQ42Wk7sN6gmE6xVh5HUVwMS9LU4Ginc3LptJ5bGUXgFPBuZmlWtRuNaIVmT4dmdRHHOJGM3Z8B03SR4bEgAegNHFaaeAQtxymYRxgdrEaFhHZ4dR+wv5/Nk4NC+qN15KSwgVORtqtJZWwYrHutDBoE/TWJC6joZguQnqRShPM93kjLqlP6gZ/+C8EUndRn6bz9WJdeS1Nm3ctDDnDST2x6mSuRVXHDqQK5cw6CGoIPVtB6jYg9RF/OEPJRxjFcZyQ9tqgYYfO1KZfJfQhBu3UMDdjD1Fhhaht2uniKkT5YU7xHqIWzynWCyM1pQfs2R6jEighy01B+j1VLjITeLphlt59hKcwiXyqdNWFssyliE1uONk4lqHOS++rYKpQ1rN+cL3qULeHpxtm6aXhOj+BJ+MKGTnhHqjFLYCcL6Lp4ckfAp/0VIXSqwpFfNKzKlSaIDlRoZbaemZhfKZM+yhxMx/puaoh9akoEgd4K0b5CULd4BO/hwg1nUccbechBSYvXQmEMqrOq7IVudZOG6erum7nrDy9KlC3R6hrfeIpBI+bWuhCXFqQE5wb0iR4zouUBfdnU5x4cYhBOj3VofSqQyWMmtOhXLikQy1eRMosjM2UaR32fte5BEgMICG5IS+FZR4a9UV+AlQ3OMrvI1DZqTtKdMabOleuA0XLpswr13R5V5s6+qYRspmZRMxd01agui1Q3egol66w+A+CUjj8twcq52TiWxkZwUf+jT0/c9GzQ8CVmapUZlWpCFdmRqWS4hJcxeVwtTBOE7qDLIaNM3ubD+RP3nSner3K61F+Alc3REDdR7iaWH61D2W0NRcR5pp3Udi80roFRZWsOylDp2am53HLxhWubgtX10ZAwbhzMW2CW2hxWa8yw+qyUu8dqWmrVxcPBFdT7cqs2lWCqxntSko/gSsl3GK4WhivmQz85KHyPbX90DlxgxtuCxzlKD9BqxsmE99DtDITK9Ar7UyjoVI1XE64rJq89E2VV74Olah8a4ycQSu7Kle3R6trJxMrjuZxz1ywpkmG9gitnOvZN4XRyMAF2OjRsKJwhwgut1Pdyq66FcHKzulWMvarSe3BauFcYrMwVIp7fKVNxiUNQYm8LYwdhvxQw4u8I8NMZhNfj1V4WI+2O7gXWGUns4mbtmmcgvnn2ooeq4oLH7gy72JdO113Qol6BquG1WZXrLoFVpkblujUpgjGmTFKeTAoZz2kNbd12mCXO2Mhj4Q4hE5l4wSmnFhhapv2bJ/AlKDHytgU1MmtHJMJqGGuL1xNyiyMoOKUYc5DSlqTiJmztmDUNIBLc7AXvdg4P9lI5nrfOprIqPu1REsUk+CE0OhQlj7mWoU6Ny297DD8cq1rbVsjQlvOxZvv1i5ckerTkSreEG8OLgzGazqsIpSmiyVaJAeeOPRjVGJfF3p21gwIPIRWNSwhvIcrv8IV4MqZq1oVYzAnWlWIC7FqGkT1Lf4Br1QPWBewAPgRMa0jBvTCae6APVRwHoaM1FaMjDviAiAvCsn5OVS+FEctgTKqiCn2DnirXn8UKCahlrYrbaxqnHM1gCIomVct9RqpQ9166DnNzGK+yk/U0gBwFbRdpe1DwQSkVanes6F7yP/nw6+OTtoL1mVujm0vMcCVVmDgetlUMrg6j6UzuelKsALn1oToq0aJGFU7DVzfUT1e7aS4idC4k1JSLu+k4k2E3/dUi2lt3VVa92vLJVoLneaeW+6Px4gariD0EVrLSbspja9zouI23SE3KsY8osTclYIzAWQV5dyA627h5t0kY0ZRWQ5IKQbVRBELulSgYaFK5q601taYcZ2lbF2F3ji3rYawd43JQxtF3na+bhqjq9LJOVoPixFPV+GF6TpehRcttIzQViwn9LXkNfoSeT9CuomYluDvxjQ2r6pouSVAmUfPhbdbhzaTplZxzvLwE5wzAcoSHYzSpHiHAG5y/VZmzA+k++b0+Kcp+XZnLpFwgz4aaN+eo+RoC5u2cDBc6ioLikwS+jwXc+WmEnq4bpE1PRsrnSzZoPcrrXNyjurxTWm9m53jPW9WDviWBTCgplt/CIq/lpPwaVOkc8EqAWutLHVuGgPuL0Wb28q1QZexttU8J11afd6kkEKHjhwQEsSAGrZYuPSglTfw0uAf/igvudHSDAt4SU36T1m1wUGE0X9KwKcvKVKtz0Ndd76JXig7C/lu3A7ae1CFTRG4QTtEBMTSAyuZO7CSDqAyWQm9JrerNVCRgo39IB76UUPDLo3qaJDfpt1CRPKag4lCv9NRz1tkRZ1Y06S+iKwYr2WXSZtymzNtYqzRtXQt/ZIVhK3Sqs5L4dtWy1gCqGbZ5ZJ32aRu0UGb26//lvaPkAu1Czs7Grb31Kh+6IteOM4VSkLkoWX6IR0s0hOz59qhLyOtGjtnhzVKss96KaVLuqEAtISm7XI0CKjma1CtsTrXna+8qGwMZmbDdBVWD82tFymJ1459iUyjG1BTBw33oCNIkFuN7DcjOMQyb8pPHTNhdcwkOJpxzMg4hGPvdF6/OBzbzg527b0xsh/h0naXlJ6zqXcZlzbo3GORF9Y6578/+/5EbxT+F+LavQisFFBe1WVwOhA2kdUvAOr35+XJeX7enh11CasgKdlIso7bDicmgpHdGr0mWl5A/yttW+XomH1ujOMacFULY4zaY60bp2fRy36+6IWOzs3BVzYHSampL7f0DAKNAeoaDBtAao6mu0fO2m39dniIcPpk4Mff/kbqP+CP+MOeK68J6Pb9RJJ+HctgEo9z3SUrejG4+0Q4Apm5Ccg+ewAKE+tx2LzJXNpjTi0HoKULjniqkDoNtYeY1C/Ye5ER9lGEUXYyeHXtpForPWTQ3avBqzhdCrduO1mLTuWtrLrcaFhH0VU+r5QOMC+j9MHPgMtu9dTPEVw+C9XopsGrayfVavSELq36KFKIkKTPaXCmUZ8X3GsMrIprUJDIyeEwk0J2y77uwCWuWhJByl3VkgRQXLnx8BWHEhei1NLhq97F4T0n1jqlChX6FdsstOZ9XljmJ0AVZoEK6CJFMEbo+wVUU0eNkq2VjXKwtyvHhSa7vHLW58oE21ofhIsT/8SKTLdApnBjfHUhtAd3OFdEn4ahhtEqdNvogHdLdVMyEvceZD6tnq4uqT/71SV3sr504yNGQA+i7hkdbVVy3yj6anZ5qZifLEE0P0l1J+rqnukkdjKzIhpTNsrWMHOA30bHOo+xDrmOValK52ys61XU77jm0PWzUiHFPvTbsXG/WyXUfi6Fo86ccUJQFDbtYAEF8XCibqaibu+JqM8N+PndMNDe2bAT+hvG/AyHDCTMzdF29UmgLpcECaO//OnZ2ekPHBH0ApicpuBxHxefViQXdnB3Gz0aEXx+fHreNunBGTGcrAQmhXZ1E7u88SVMg8p1eVk7ek2bUrWqrEU9Ey2ixcS35ALwLdWEO/dRjQmJZ6Ti7PswDAmk+nzayOC+rdR0Vlaom67sYt7F2Oam8yYvUf9c12UMXSXxUWHGQa/FVNcz6ORYS9qK3KLF9FlWWi1T9vYhYAPZd9D9QuyWP2n/2m7fnjYPv05CPIfnu2/0l3aG2oxgWAHC5wFaLQFoVv6HsyOAzoQbJJdtmjSsiBp9VWVz2QaLhm1r6F9VAzD0tW0rKVRb/oeCsjmQ0/zFDpL/n98j5hdMGRBeDQNlwhcmQby2vfS6Kxh/wTyfAvPT9S/1Z7/+5U6g54Zo7wTz3ppPg/nAdbS86WO9vU5LlHLzAeRtEcMSmKdgT+M/utDYLsKc0i0n3EOc80hfkPOyrbRrY2hn9hnR08XxoDBwX1bO8OOYfxbSzBnT28fC3x3mvZ3MZquMa4LtfF6VkH3j25CHpm7zaDrnnI+mvbQ5ygDzcup3tFoW3AtbACydZXxIn5daJXZfBPRqHuif3wLox2tx/nxALyexNV0j27KufG5qF3MjDIe4S5XXxmlRuVoD61egvxMAPxc/E9LfAPQ+MogMrB80fYpBMp4m9v5vcyikd1Ok/9zDTHcSrWeQ3t0e6Z3Rl6K8Por0xoCFuemVtWkfB8MZDGafX4z0k+AVq7poGAbRlVZAsmPMq7oTUJVLb2MnO9/O+Pq1nARIGgbcBJs2OWKEn7Gh8DFy/fbCqbsCPZtqUmcNlVuroPKuQW9pZNvklalUHhtRQu8UsZoNuNHy0r6w6DmVhKkGXA+MuQkpT88K8guB3hwK6B3I+0sAvZqGvjWqqluca4KEqcQeNphQISts04YotVMr0N8N6H8ujf6X708YgWejSxYDZ21ygWRuG++1S6F/d+tP+P5M75Z/TbVBVk+6FzU3JJ5u/f3NXcLLo7Pz7fO35RnKSJ3Bi/a8Pjt6vz3lmYH7vyqHe5S1F53I2Yf21a43SY+i8Gb79hyQ40PGpZMMOldrXTpC4LaGKq1oxGvpwDkLTXl3P3957J752LErh2XsDgebKqbAPzU5oBmnawzRTPUY3pOu4Xygg4b3cudN5/f37Z8b0tGY/txwflfvfT2GevGX18e/PM80j/G38pfts7u2O1L7jJ5L9R23jxDpHoZ27drSW9HfZ8VFW+I+YuCk4dIJfsU+w0fSp1qxfzwVwSf5qqHodPP+qV15bJj08qHYfaNcIhoru3vGa7zeD/VC5XfnLIWIZaPb3zMLy/JTwqcDxktiMG32x45gc0f/qTvKjo7d5+6O/UNMXzpSS4/vGXPZwBnXcW0YqHqlYS69/zI3jA82zOz5C257fWgwsCsYrGCwgsGvAQwOYjCe12mzPyED7cA/J12KBN8QNXgp195tXh6Xb853ePLs2emP32W5UyFd5P6JIpXwOl3+unzXjoHqL1uorPXTkzfHSXnatu/+nkkjLipygU+fbZUG+8leZz+pT7WfrBXml7Cfpo4yVYbKM3TO2zo3ldWwn2BEaVVZE4RqGrHaT/fEUTa/nsQQwhuKYCR32ikMd3mWMGyczgI3uRCHsmzixLLR0yESPTdEcmdlZlj6eVVmVmVmVWbuuTJzdzBQKxisYLCCwa8BDFbL5ue2bNx1lo3+dMtG+l/CspkMutWNsjGWFiZEaHIjrMxLq2JuvRelddo10q+Wzf2wbObjfIfN1lVhBdfWkEUM6AddKGiJBOsPEOzVGzbaTQ0bPzVs5tYevrMus1t5fNVlVl1m1WXuty5zd8MmrmCwgsEKBr8GMFgNm5/ZsImfsMTdR8IgPa0bMZ3XxEBHZ/twQu6nTumJpghD4KNSN69lSCnQkyEZ0UQdjJZ5WzmRG5owZVvVeeU7rcrKyCbM7Mmk4ySWXXMBPKjB3nDxMoMewBVRo4rOFcaH5WsZ/h/36HQCDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KODg4IDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL01ldGFkYXRhL1N1YnR5cGUvWE1ML0xlbmd0aCAzMTY1Pj5zdHJlYW0NCjw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+Cjx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuNC1jMDA1IDc4LjE0NzMyNiwgMjAxMi8wOC8yMy0xMzowMzowMyAgICAgICAgIj4KICAgPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4KICAgICAgPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIKICAgICAgICAgICAgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIgogICAgICAgICAgICB4bWxuczpwZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20vcGRmLzEuMy8iCiAgICAgICAgICAgIHhtbG5zOnhtcE1NPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvbW0vIgogICAgICAgICAgICB4bWxuczpkYz0iaHR0cDovL3B1cmwub3JnL2RjL2VsZW1lbnRzLzEuMS8iPgogICAgICAgICA8eG1wOkNyZWF0ZURhdGU+MjAxMy0wOS0xMFQxMToyNDo1NS0wODowMDwveG1wOkNyZWF0ZURhdGU+CiAgICAgICAgIDx4bXA6TW9kaWZ5RGF0ZT4yMDE2LTA5LTA5VDA4OjM0OjA2LTA3OjAwPC94bXA6TW9kaWZ5RGF0ZT4KICAgICAgICAgPHhtcDpNZXRhZGF0YURhdGU+MjAxNi0wOC0yNlQxNjoxMjoyNi0wNzowMDwveG1wOk1ldGFkYXRhRGF0ZT4KICAgICAgICAgPHBkZjpQcm9kdWNlcj5kb1BERiBWZXIgNy4zIEJ1aWxkIDM4MSAoV2luZG93cyA3IEJ1c2luZXNzIEVkaXRpb24gKFNQIDEpIC0gVmVyc2lvbjogNi4xLjc2MDEgKHg2NCkpPC9wZGY6UHJvZHVjZXI+CiAgICAgICAgIDx4bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPnV1aWQ6MWYyZmQ2MDMtZThmYy00YjAxLWIxOGEtZjZhMDk2NGUxYTJmPC94bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPgogICAgICAgICA8eG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD51dWlkOjA2YTQ2NTMxLThiMDAtNGQ3YS05YmRhLTA0NDc3MmE2MTkzODwveG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD4KICAgICAgICAgPGRjOmZvcm1hdD5hcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9wZGY8L2RjOmZvcm1hdD4KICAgICAgPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+CiAgIDwvcmRmOlJERj4KPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0idyI/Pg0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjg5MCAwIG9iag0KPDwvVHlwZSAvT2JqU3RtIC9OIDY2L0ZpcnN0IDYxNi9MZW5ndGggMzE5MS9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj5zdHJlYW0NCnic7Vtrb9tGFv0rhBfYOsAOOffO201cOE69WyDNZpOg/ZAGCz6GiReKZMhqk/TX77mU5YiOFKt57Katm0KaK3KGw/s4c86QNskUujDJFuQDvl3hDOPbFz4lfIeCXJQfIk7QhEaSM2NhtS7YaUaD0DAODS7Y64CGQSNaNGxhNEvDFYYSoeEL48ijgav5aNCQsUjjIxWWArqL4Rw+CB0CyS9cOC0DkilcjHLIopGkB2acAgbEoJ6skTGKoB3mQxGNiOEpFQGzLyzrIrDBgExF1AEnMxeRMCnLBg25L0w3snRnV0TLcrIvEjvMBUZimQbHIhknvVKRrME4RhfJ4y6toYK0NZgZ/IhWgIdwAmln0dHAz9rj6hYOIx2S9PAFkR96BGkNPeBuCkMP+Jui9LAarSQ9LK7BEf2sZWl59MWdEycr5+EaRuPm4US0KGE8zJUMD78FacnILkorwC1wDVqIufUY2Rg4xXqWlkUPL+OZgB5expPAWy/jiWOsl/Gskx4ynhUXYj5kHIJvg4zs4Jzbt6uTgmP1/f69A9aEiFIgJAKx0vErrb+6VT34fh/h0rjHVjG3XqF3VE0yrJqGmWwIScfmVvUQGYikfVRUD+t5ni6QlLy0H+V28bTA3enSIubGlwH+Y8+DHd1gP6se/9ws3pzl6uHs7Oez6ok0j6bT2eLwENM8eoiPBwWSVYY8PKzuPsYPj/HvR3gY9vHTQo7pZ9XxUaFLVx3Pc704nU3v1Yt85facv7y9k8JW9799Wj2YTfPw8WzlDK8je9Jam7TuDDa5j45qOINZWW+squvOq5YTkcl13xgaOUPuZijhNV9YZ0vJvGBN6aWIUY5oDL5IFAZf/Gf/4WzyZnI6zbfWXDN5cx+/VE/2b615qPohzxenbT5/KtlQBuBGwBUS8iQ4XUpxBOdKraV2xOkB3670qEnSZErMZLB9eDY4e2NOrDkNbtDOmMY1tcIJTqGojWo4NCqxbnptfN2HuDEn7DgnMC3UZjChxBWQE2awoxvsHXOCRzmBfFilA/4N6UDV8f2nghglQMiZ0rEgXCo1yj1oXAqgAlBdt9FvNl1gyuf7AltwzU/zn6amYvyvdbj1nvSKqI+Vp+4d7Rf4D3lZBpv0MNO/V//Ik18yYKN40l85OH+OjyctwoKvX6U9wSCP93tM5qAY+iHQNfoimmeLr9vZZDY/+IvWd0+0Xmbzd0+qk3nOT/LrxXE9mcx+XlyX4HZU7bHNZDsTFDU2Ktt7gwT3rJK2NqQ66t7065H9F9z76Hj/9jevX06KX/L8HE65s4f57X1zeLuZdW8KHJie39l7sVicHVTVq1evylemnM2fV8DNVL1+sXg52VuedPC6r0cnwh7OPG9f5Jd1BVN19aKuMHyFPn19cPTwux9WFz1q57N+Nn95wCWCiRkMZ5yf5fbOHpe0d3j7rDhfvJnkO3sLuEfVk9Pn04MWUc5zHDw/q6er41J36kU+ff5icQBH/00CoM5Pf80HRPD70pRTD6a4YD1Z/vJq2aGZTbpxaJaH+/rl6eTNwdH8tJ7sHV7k1V//8lrf+1o+j76+zK/blUzmUHLudnV28S3OHJq3qkf3nkreYB1H1QJEjS0ZgPrsoq6MgYOELJgyOVlPw5D5VjIf58wWSNpCL1HmIknegswqe66AzFByy8wV3rEsOfx0tz7PJ7i76jI71V3cf/XttJ11p9Pn1Y+n06Pp+emlvbqODE3LC0j/UUmbHUs6hBLnSk0LT/GxpCg8I5Ze1lyg6Zq9VtJYGt9TwVhVzf+6gk9Oov6ICg7rFVzbLrsOyxa3WJis9b1Kra8VVureJLI52vQFV3BTLw7EO1frFwvZUMHd6Rz1uZjv7VrLn6F2kUAXJSrleVGab8uSCfkAOmpiyY7tqizBR7EoMxKSSiGEoGXL9LVI34+uy4HzDwFdZqfV/L4q/bAC/SzVbjeQOruseDA5TQkEGNF3WnDnLcGrz4q+npznrZXswXh4TPWeFl6w0gnjJyFhl3aIsTQOsbqm1pxer7Vs6kym6VWjjVaIuVOx7qIK2fuYQIlco9+lgyLB1miQ53gxBVNCnBTe6tUUE9jcBR28P6KCG2jgFu429gLmDLHQdb6JyrXgsZZl9mDnYHE++96FJsW0gbuJgBxxt4AoQHtpUFcoGfZusJdc1u/I3dz20F+h8ztEm9hvjDZuRKIr+vLS9oDseH2wzbrjHHh7Y7NVnppO2Y6Tir1rVbRgu5RtCwduCrZ/J9gyA1BfrM1DrMXEWu0DfXSs132AKfddTk3jnXJQiIhwG1TE6qD6LubsXOhrV2+M9UivsAuIKSYbQxmh9lkgCzbUutg7xtp/0lhfFXHwbEKMRftglgl6/dJGrMGIrg/2aBXNHsqPfVDecINVtDEqhaZRLvbUxM4lajdWdhwFO/FyCiK/IoQOimWwEW3ox4+ONpqjBE22BoYBfhqkpaWOVYQXVN9G7lNNDSfeGO0wjjbWKZziIqGQGdGmwZZly3veMdrhw0B9a8ChFX+Lancj1a4pdqYJXjV9CHBMrhHMtlc56+ACUcp9tyGYpEfBFHGKwggR+sLIMg4pKTsyAtPsPkK1Cwg42RfC7cIgaGBBBBHBQxYb4sHUHN7akuWRtyn2scMECVzKNXlAVgNxZxM1cIapVVtD8OlWJ5PajbmRxqifnKyagvopyo5iGOwB9VPcMTfie3LjLZdeEf1r0CASYVEeJ8d3V0cCp5YQHM3ns1eCFfBQKgkeZ+S67PqJ7tcXtuM1rDiezM5zN3R8J8tw16MsaxuP+utVazgr6z3yreudCja3HgtEaLLdlGUjrCUps1jIjZWSEgGOhX/ZQsGudoaG2VyPGCt3p5W7l/5cqaC7eqWC8vd58WLW7T8Y+PA2aXTV0SKNqjVFw1BDm7UO76J1ZPKv5qfg7++62a672Ubq4Vataig8ZUPbqWicU51tGcLHZ+70n1Tf2E+kb+7qlbz5zBfaLKNWhQC5JCUJnI1SCLIzJ4WRQJyuyqW32fNbdjLkicXn2cm4ishD8dBIO3QW1LwhrNbaAi4ab8HNUov8SS34RcqR8yZEJrrCw0057CE74IYgslvagDjYuyGy7FbstOPiGIpEYmIhngrn5HkEa/nJDU8khvb6TktKm+AEMAKfgKs6e2WnhdbYwTs7LaOD/4+dFtJjdq2b2HeeVW7IKGt6rVInz0iY+tx733cp/EmR6LfttCyDsnGnJV2DRJ/qQmnbhg5YHzvQLknyQaUs685Bxy0rwUglxOG5XRx44Edv5FAcbeRQeh9IfTkbOaRpNxSJNi0JjmjIJHTXLRnOsJ9g1u0RltAmLDE6gbQFYaC/MywZSRTrA5hLTLKvAARp26hqrpMiZ+u6N5DaNm4gj2xvoOWDoYW21byzyEFJ0lB69rRe99EO5DxI7iZ2JYIpuZrK+Cm2cJlHlc/mC6/8dZqDQiQiT8mMd8106Eh2GiMyHDSn8yrW0SiO2YRe1xBHfKv651meXsi8dxkP6yuMR0S3qPEo77ZAeMIm2Wffjevs+MA4ahBNxFYeobsiAq5Eh8VQRGjEZXOETuYPhU7jd0BMk1PbIn5BHm/byC3UVxcQ07pJTYq9qzdtoHC6QacPRiezDZ2YyiSPfp3TY2jScUhYm4aEdVz64fWjkj8FMoUxMr33EfCfB5ncBmQKaYxMfsd9MdI7PveOw7tmhksCfwq+9FEC7SUtYoxr5gif+I+FT6PdzTaYHEPfK9wR8Kllp1KfW5Wtdtq0QKg6bcAnc8OePhyfeBs+WZCj6FzBprRueBCwxp60ZC5J5ibSpQ+ykEJc8afAKDNmT+aGPQlGmU3syfkyrmOUdeWO79uRtjuilOwVyZuoxLo0HrTJD8+TIHxIlB6Y9Lo9ej9nq9LT5Ixb23b/fWBVHL2f4ygYg5BKFBDSEFVk0yGulDSURYsk2IRVN1zqg7HKblV6YPUx2bB8bYdLk1y8xCrZ4ZH81dGWFLHSmjJgwUc+E/L5U+DVmFOZG0414NWVdw+g15I8L5d3TMwSrnQkwNeueOV2w6tAXMYw/AXAwKzkreToBrCM8v6kaPxLc4RWW5XfZrT6st8mRHaP33DyXWp9Ui5SK28TRpVS71TXNNpzMgxFuAGt7A2zuu6Z2PFWtNqq/LCCpuDjgFahBI9KZoVWAbe1zF6H1bQIAZWCmCCZTUkf/9bv8Fct62Blb8iVgJXV74IVlosRWAFOrgWryzv+tx7+Ouetc7+wI4b87/rIfwEB92jqDQplbmRzdHJlYW0NCmVuZG9iag0KODkxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlIC9YUmVmL1dbMSA0IDJdL0luZGV4WzAgODkyXS9TaXplIDg5Mi9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0RlY29kZVBhcm1zPDwvQ29sdW1ucyA3L1ByZWRpY3RvciAxMj4+L0xlbmd0aCA0MTgvSW5mbyAxMyAwIFIgL1Jvb3QgMTUgMCBSIC9JRFs8MUE1QUQzOUIwNEI4NjgxMDJDOEM3RkYxOTg2NEIyQzc+PDRGRTRFMTJGQUY3MTVBOTIzMzFCNjU3NDAzRTZEMDI0Pl0+PnN0cmVhbQ0KeJztk7tKQ0EQhmc32qnB1lYRK1OoYAyKdzAqRpSojRdQC22FYLBQ8EJeQBubdGJlnkCwMKSwsRS8dDb6CMnxJPMnmMVgIic5QSbNl39mZ8/M7Iym7M+ydI5KMYkco/3Hs1/QSmeI0mdkaWWrVth3bVo2j7/F2f5G3KNC4BI4w9TTxVqNwj4JPQaOgBPwzxpxU7AHoRdAH+f1HuF82u5wbgj+ADgMBo285jj+Jc7x7desn8OsOz5xfhznN8EN2C/AGOxdoJ/veYwV98uXMuqYN/JEv9Ug6MX5HsPv5fvvEw7OQa1o9yGwijrWUV8UehvE++g16DC4DHvE6FsT2Gf0Nz9X+Xlc5L4lPjiP0A7rm/Pq1ht6wnc6S+6fxt5loD3Q6Qr3uKGwx0JhPZLn+sqY2xXX86o3cp9OjD4dlBl3aMQduV6P0+Q6twp1lkvux6Xr+f838nsMVPwewuqS5z2Z04r8rs+J8Gdm9+eUHhx99yj1/vK9FM71l/Dfwx/4Yz23rs+/UCgUCoVCoVAoFNaKimgvyfo1zuxuYTa/EX0BQsRn3g0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCg0Kc3RhcnR4cmVmDQozNjQzOA0KJSVFT0YNCg==';
```

Comment: In some cases this can easily eat up the 30k something character limit...

Answer (score -9):

If you need an external PDF to demonstrate the problem, you have probably not yet reduced the problem to the smallest problem that reproduces the problem. So you probably do not have an acceptable question for this site.

Comment: If it's a question about how to use the API of a PDF-modifying library, then your inputs and outputs are PDFs.  Obviously it's better if you can write an MCVE with short text inputs/outputs, or describe something about the PDF instead of just linking to binaries, but I don't agree with your description.  I partly agree with your conclusion, though, that it might not make a good SO question.  But people that know the library might not need to look at your PDFs if they see what you're doing wrong in your MCVE code.

Comment: not sure why this answer gets voted down, it seems correct to me. maybe a bit shorter than the top-voted ones, but with the same content.

Comment: @cari: at least some of the down-votes may come from the fact that the answer paints with too broad a brush. Personally, I agree with the underlying sentiment. Not all questions that can be asked, even if presented well, belong on Stack Overflow. And IMHO those that require specialized, complex inputs from an external data file are very likely to be inappropriate. But it's impossible to know for sure that's the case in every situation. I wouldn't down-vote this answer myself, but I would like to see a more nuanced approach, including a good explanation of viable alternatives for the situation.